# Default option in select box is not working with "selected"

Tags: html, angularjs

for some reason the default option that I want is not showing up. When I had a empty option "Select Job Status" as the default it worked. It doesn't work when the value="" is not empty. But when I created a plunkr for this post it works fine?? What could be causing it not work in my project?

[newplunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B2TpxzOju2ADRFhvdQTR?p=preview)

```
<label style="margin-left:33px">Status:</label>
  <select style="width: 100px" ng-model="currentItem.JobStatus">
  <option value="Active" selected>Active</option>
  <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
   <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
</select>
```

This form is for creating a new object, so the ng-model is not binding to something that would already have data.

Comment: The plnkr you created has no angular library loaded, so ng-model is being ignored.

Comment: see updated plunkr. the selected option is not showing up. same as my project.

Comment: I don't see currentItem defined anywhere.  If you add this in your controller in the plnkr and removed the selected from the option it works.   $scope.currentItem = {JobStatus: 'Active'};

Comment: not sure how to give you credit

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered this when you stated:

> ... the ng-model is not binding to something that would already have data

Currently there is no currentItem  defined in any scope, so trying to bind to the JobStatus property of an undefined variable will result with nothing.

Edit: I took too long to type this, so @Scott beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you want default option. Can't you use something like below.

```
<select style="width: 100px" ng-model="currentItem.JobStatus">
      <option value="" selected>Select</option>
      <option value="Active">Active</option>
      <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
      <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
</select>
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Thanks